# Button linked to AutoCompleteTextField

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to implement exact code as in CodenameOne's *TIP: Don't Use ComboBox* article.

```
AutoCompleteTextField act = new AutoCompleteTextField(jTypesArr);
act.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);
Button down = new Button();
FontImage.setMaterialIcon(down, FontImage.MATERIAL_KEYBOARD_ARROW_DOWN);
add(BorderLayout.center(act).
add(BorderLayout.EAST, down));
down.addActionListener(evt -> {
act.showPopup();
});
```

However, down button with `act.showPopup();` seems not to be working - it doesn't open the dropdown list.
If you click just on AutoCompleteTextField, everything works properly.

Please let me know what is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I think this should work. Try `down.addActionListener(evt -> callSerially(() -> act.showPopup()));`

Comment: @ShaiAlmog, sorry for the late response. It still doesn't seem to be working. I added some `println()` statements to debug it, and it seem to  be calling btn ActionListener and `callSerially()` properly. However, `act.showPopup();` just doesn't open the list. Also, I noticed that `act.setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);` doesn't change shown amount of elements in the list.

Comment: Looking at the code it seems there's a regression with that method and it needs to be rewritten. Can you please file an issue on that?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog created an issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3334 . 
Should I create another one for the `setMinimumElementsShownInPopup(5);` method? Or there is a solution

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a bug

Comment: @ShaiAlmog , is there any equivalent methods/ways for `com.codename1.ui.spinner.Picker` to have something like `showPopup()` assigned to a "down" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue closed, `showPopup()` works now.
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3334